# Phone to phone detection/communication protocol?

Tags: bluetooth, nfc, mobile-development

I'm trying to figure out if there is a protocol for wireless phone to phone communication (so not WIFI) where an application can determine that another phone with the same application is in the same room (or a couple meters) and transfer data between the applications.

Bluetooth would work but I want the application to pre-establish the handshake instead of requiring the Bluetooth handshake.

NFC would be perfect if the range was more than 10cm.

Is there anything else out there that might work?

Comment: Why is WIFI Direct not an option?

Comment: @MichaelRoland does WIFI Direct mean setting up one device as a WIFI hotspot and the other device connected to it or is this a protocol I'm not yet aware of?

Comment: Essentially yes. However, WiFi Direct makes the initialization ceremony more comfortable by automating the process of choosing who becomes the host (access point) and how becomes the client. Moreover, there are methods to spawn groups on the fly without requiring pre-shared keys.